# rectjs: material ui: TextField: show error if type and min is not valid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having a TextField, I want it to be number and also `min=0.0001`  i.e for number greater than zero

I am trying

```
<TextField 
    InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0.00001 } }} 
    type="number" id="outlined-basic" 
/>
```

If i enter 0 in the input and leave, it does not show any error

Comment: That's normal behaviour in HTML. See the following W3Schools [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min). In other words, you need to handle this type of validation manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**min** Input prop in html is validated only after the form is submitted (It will prevent the form from submitting if the values are invalid).

See [Constraint Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation)

If you want to use a realtime validation. You should consider using [Formik](https://formik.org/)

Answer (score 0):

use **error** prop of rectjs: material *ui: TextField* :
my solution snippet for your doubt is :

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
const [num, setNum] = useState();
return (
    <>
      <TextField
        InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0.00001 } }}
        type={"number"}
        value={num}
        onChange={(e) => setNum(e.target.value)}
        error={num && num < 0.00001}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

if you Enter **number < 0.00001** that this TextField will be colored as **Red**